# How to get seed of current state of random generator in goal to place it in set.seed() function

Tags: r, random

I have to repeat some statistical procedure based on pseudorandom numbers several times (about 100 000), this procedure is written in pure R. After each step (there are 100 000 steps or call it iterations) I would like to get current state (getting seed would be proper I suppose) of random generator, and after this one step/iteration of procedure I collect only part of the entire output because it's too large to store (it's the value of optimized goal function and a few other statistics ). After inspection of total output (which is 100 000 long) I would like to pick the best solution and run procedure corresponding to it again, for this I need to set the state of random generator which correspond for choosen solution. There is `set.seed` but getting seed is no straight forward, there is `.Random.seed` but how could it help with above problem ?

Comment: Just get a vector of 100,000 integers, `n`, and for the ith iteration do `set.seed(n[i])`. Then if you choose the jth output as the 'best' you just use `n[j]` for your seed... or am I missing something?

Comment: @konvas its ok you don't miss anything, but which n to choose ? shouldn't it be vector of some prime numbers etc. ?

Comment: No, you can set `n[i]` to be any (random) integer (beforehand, so you know what it is). Then if you do `set.seed(n[i])` it will produce a sequence of pseudorandom numbers (the same each time you set the seed to the same value). Does this make sense? For example whenever you do `set.seed(1)`, R will generate the same sequence of random numbers every time.

Comment: @konvas I understand, from what range of values I can choose seeds ?

Comment: Just choose a vector of random integers of length 100,000. For example `n <- sample.int(.Machine$integer.max, 100000)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `set.seed(x)` at the beginning of each iteration. Make sure you can identify the seed that was used before you started the process, so that you can use it later. For example:

```
for (seed in seeds) {
  set.seed(i)
  print(sprintf('using seed = %d\n', seed))
  do_your_stuff(...)
}
```

In a comment you asked:

> how to choose seed in proper manner - shouldn't it be some "random" prime numbers not the simple series of integers (if we talk about vector of containing seeds) ?

I'm not sure how it matters if `seeds` is simply a sequence (like `1:100`) or random prime numbers. As far as I know, any seed number `X` is just as good as any other `Y`. But if that's important to you, then you can grab a list of prime numbers from somewhere (for example [here](http://primes.utm.edu/lists/small/1000.txt)) and use `sample` to randomize them, for example:

```
seeds <- sample(c(7, 17, 19, 23, 1019, 1021))
```

Comment: I was thinking about it, but how to choose seed in proper manner - shouldn't it be some "random" prime numbers not the simple series of integers (if we talk about vector of containing seeds) ?